# AmStockChart values in legend disappear after selecting a different dataset from the original

Tags: javascript, legend, amcharts, legend-properties, amstock

I have an `AmStockChart` that has a data set with more than one value. The problem that I run into is that the second value will not display, in the legend, after selecting a different data set and returning the the previous one. Is there a way to force the legend to refresh after selecting a new data set?

[Here is a github Gist of an example of the problem](https://gist.github.com/aauberg/8bbb7b5b8ca67c5703a6)

Comment: Indeed it looks like a bug. I'll let you know when it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.! I solved it by following way.

Try using latest files(all of these not just amcharts.js):

1) amchart.js

2) amstock.js

3) serial.js

```
Here is the code with links:

<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="http://www.a`enter code here`mcharts.com/lib/3/amstock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Hope it helps you..!!